# .NET Core Worker project "Start" with "0" argument(s)

Tags: .net-core, service-worker, worker

I got a worker project and I prepared a few things in it (mainly log4net with a config and a worker). When I run it from Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine, however...

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<SomeWorker>();
                    // DI...
                });
```

After using it as a Windows service, I receive an error. Am I missing something here? It seems that there isn't really much that could actually go wrong.

```
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z ##[section]Starting: Start Windows Service: ServiceName
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z ==============================================================================
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z Task         : Start Windows Service
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z Description  : Start a windows service.
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z Version      : 8.0.0
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z Author       : Michael Barry
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/jabbera/my-vsts-tasks)
2020-04-28T14:11:27.2038348Z ==============================================================================
2020-04-28T14:11:28.3796348Z Starting Windows Services ServiceName and setting startup type to: Automatic.
2020-04-28T14:11:28.9180348Z ##[error]Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot start service ServiceName on computer '.'."
2020-04-28T14:11:28.9648348Z ##[section]Finishing: Start Windows Service: ServiceName
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably start the service without arguments. When you start the service from VS the Main method is called with a single startup argument (%LAUNCHER_ARGS%). When starting it as a Windows service this argument is probably missing.